# Cannot decode json in PHP, created by .NET JSONSerializer

Tags: php, json, httpwebrequest

I serialize some object in .NET using JsonSerializer (on a Windows machine)
The serialized string looks like this:

```
{
   "ItemId":"someID",
   "Properties":
   {
      "Title":"someTitle",
      "Text":"someText",
      "Time":"someTime"
   }
}
```

Then I send it to a my Linux server, using HttpWebRequest.
On the Linux side I run PHP (using LAMP), when I get it on PHP server the Json string looks exactly as it looks before I send it, but when I try to decode it ( using `json_decode($myJsonStr, true)` ) I get Syntax Error.
My Json also include some Unicode characters (Hebrew letters)
Any ideas?

Best Regards, Nadav

Comment: And what's that error message? What does `json_last_error()` say? How does the JSON look in a hexeditor? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you filled your `$myJsonStr`, but sometimes it's best to decode JSON taking the input directly from PHP's streams, like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data);
```

This is the way I use to get around one of those incompatibilities when receiving JSON from third-parties.